# Replacing a specific Char from a String between two positions

Tags: java, replace, stringbuffer

Consider the following String:

```
String str = "XFB_PART~\XFB_IDF~\XFB_MODE~0\XFB_LOCALITEM~\XFB_REMOTEITEM~\XFB_MSG~tool\ soundgarden~\ASYNCHRONOUS~0\BROADCAST~0\XFB_LOCALAGT~"
```

What I would like to do is replace all the backslashes between `XFB_MSG` and `ASYNCHRONOUS` with commas (so every time you see a backslash, replace it with a comma).

Here's what I did:

```
            stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(str);


            for (int i = stringBuffer.indexOf("XFB_MSG"); i<stringBuffer.indexOf("ASYNCHRONOUS"); i++){

                if(stringBuffer.charAt(i)=='\\'){
                    stringBuffer = stringBuffer.replace(i, i, ",");
                }
            }
```

Problem is, once the condition `if (stringBuffer.charAt(i)=='\\')` is met, the compiler keeps on entering and replacing the char even when i changes value and as a result I'm getting an infinite loop with commas being constantly inserted:

```
XFB_PART~\XFB_IDF~\XFB_MODE~0\XFB_LOCALITEM~\XFB_REMOTEITEM~\XFB_MSG~tool,,,,,,,,\ soundgarden~\ASYNCHRONOUS~0\BROADCAST~0\XFB_LOCALAGT~
```

Once again, the objective is to only replace all the backslashes between `XFB_MSG` and `ASYNCHRONOUS` and leave the rest of the string intact. The positions can change, and so can the value between those two parameters. So I have to search for them like that and try to find a way to replace the backslashes between them with commas.

Any idea why am I having an infinite loop, and if you happen to have a better way to do this, please do not hesitate to let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: You probably want to use [String.replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,char%29).  Something like: `int start = str.indexOf("XFB_MSG"); int end = str.indexOf("ASYNCHRONOUS"); str = str.substring(0, start) + str.substring(start, end).replace('\\', ',') + str.substring(end);`

Comment: Thank you. Your method is way better and simpler, and you didn't even have to use StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
stringBuffer = stringBuffer.replace(i, i, ",");
```

to:

```
stringBuffer = stringBuffer.replace(i, i+1, ",");
```

and now it's working.

But I still don't understand why it's working now and why earlier I had an infinite loop.

Comment: Read [the method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#replace%28int,int,java.lang.String%29) carefully.

Comment: The end index is exclusive, where the start index is not. So, the end index should go one beyond the index you are trying to include. substring has similar nuances with its indices, which makes sense when you use it, but if you haven't used it in a while gets aggravating.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.